# How to mount HDFS on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ubuntu-14.04

So,I can't mount HDFS on Ubuntu 14.04. Mucommander not working, fuse not working, can somebody explain me with images or make me some tutorial. Thanks, best regards.

Answer (score 10):

I successfuly did it today using [instructions on Cloudera site](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-6-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_28.html)

```
wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/one-click-install/trusty/amd64/cdh5-repository_1.0_all.deb      
sudo dpkg -i cdh5-repository_1.0_all.deb     
sudo apt-get update       
sudo apt-get install hadoop-hdfs-fuse
sudo mkdir -p <mount_point>
hadoop-fuse-dfs dfs://<name_node_hostname>:<namenode_port> <mount_point>
```

What OS and version of HDFS do you use?

Comment: Hi Sir,
My OS: 14.04.1
HADOOP:2.4.0

Best Regards.

Comment: I mounted HDFS 2.3 on Ubuntu 12.04. It should work for your environment too.

Comment: Sir I'm getting this error "‘/mnt/hdfs’: Transport endpoint is not connected" Best Regards.

Answer (score 5):

You have to add the CDH5 repository first (tested on 15.04):

`wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/one-click-install/trusty/amd64/cdh5-repository_1.0_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i cdh5-repository_1.0_all.deb
sudo apt-get update`

Then proceed with [@AlexDvoretsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26165829/90874).

Answer (score 2):

Alternative instructions for CDH5 repository installation on Ubuntu 16.04: From [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh5_install.html#topic_4_4_1__p_44).

`sudo wget 'https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/debian/wheezy/amd64/cdh/cloudera.list' -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudera.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hadoop-hdfs-fuse`

Then back to [@AlexDvoretsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26165829/90874)

Comment: It's a good start, but repo authentication problems still remain. See http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh5_install.html how to download and enable the repository key with apt-key.

Answer (score 1):

I developed a python program that uses FUSE to mount HDFS as a standard filesystem, it also works with Kerberos and it works well: https://github.com/EDS-APHP/py-hdfs-mount