# How to mount Hadoop HDFS

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, hadoop, docker

I am trying to mount Hadoop HDFS that I have set up in Google engine in a docker container running Ubuntu 14.04. Can anyone show me the necessary steps? I have tried to following some poor guides on the internet but it seems like all the packages are broken.

**I will add 500 bounty to an answer that is correct.**

Comment: I tried following this since I thought hdfs maybe was the solution? However I am unable to download the software following the steps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155254/how-to-mount-hdfs-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an easy way to test hdfs but I just mounted s3fs inside a docker ubuntu container. S3fs also uses fuse so I hope it would have similar requirements. I had to run the container as -privileged to get it to work otherwise fuze mount the filesystem and would get the following error. `fuse: failed to open /dev/fuse: Operation not permitted`

I am not sure if google allows you to run containers in privileged mode though so I don't know if this will work for you even if you could mount hdfs.

Comment: If it doesn't allow privileged mode can't I use S3fs?

Comment: No without privileged mode I was not able to get s3fs working

Comment: That sucks, that mean I can't mount at all?