# Copy files to local from multiple directories in HDFS for last 24 hours

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs

I have a problem with getting data from HDFS to local.
I have for example:

```
/path/to/folder/report1/report1_2019_03_24-03_10*.csv
/path/to/folder/report1/report1_2019_03_24-04_12*.csv
...
/path/to/folder/report1/report1_2019_03_25-05_12*.csv
/path/to/folder/report1/report1_2019_03_25-06_12*.csv
/path/to/folder/report1/report1_2019_03_25-07_11*.csv
/path/to/folder/report1/report1_2019_03_25-08_13*.csv
/path/to/folder/report2/report2_out_2019_03_25-05_12*.csv
/path/to/folder/report2/report2_out_2019_03_25-06_11*.csv
/path/to/folder/report3/report3_TH_2019_03_25-05_12*.csv
```

So I need enter in each of these folders (report1, report2, report3... But not all of them starts with "report") and then CSV files that are from previous 24hour copy to local and that should be done each morning at 4 am (I can schedule that with crontab).
The problem is that I don't know how to iterate over file and pass timestamp as an argument.

I have tried with something like this (found on Stack Overflow)

```
/datalake/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -ls /path/to/folder/report1/report1/*    |   tr -s " "    |    cut -d' ' -f6-8    |     grep "^[0-9]"    |    awk 'BEGIN{ MIN=1440; LAST=60*MIN; "date +%s" | getline NOW } { cmd="date -d'\''"$1" "$2"'\'' +%s"; cmd | getline WHEN; DIFF=NOW-WHEN; if(NOW > DIFF){ print "Migrating: "$3; system("datalake/hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -copyToLocal /path/to/local_dir/"$3) }}'
```

But this one is copying files older than I few days and it's copying only files from one directory (in this case report1).

Is there any way to make this more flexible and correct. It would be great if this can be solver with bash, not with Python.
Any suggestion is welcomed or link to a good answer with a similar problem.

Also, it's not necessary to be in some loop. It's OK for me to use the separated code line for each report.

Comment: it may be that I'm not understanding correctly, but why not just copy `/path/to/folder/*` or `/path/to/folder/report*`?

Comment: @Tiberiu Because these folders are getting reports (csv files) with each hour each day and it's getting bigger and bigger. I don't need all of these files, just for each day I need previous 24 hours.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not sure what the bash command would be, but if it were me I'd have another folder structure, where files that weren't copied would all reside, so you could get everything in there. Once copied they could be moved to the general `report` folder. Would greatly simplify your command and also leave a trace in case something went wrong, but I come to this with the programming mentality.

Comment: @Tiberiu The problem is that I'm not the one who created folder structure. If it's ok I only works for one folder (report) I can just use that bash script with minor changes for any other folder.

Comment: Did you try to mount your *HDFS* (with `hadoop-fuse-dfs` or similar)?

Comment: If you mount *HDFS*, you could use them as *local* fs! Look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/26155254/1765658

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**note:** I was unable to test this, but you could test this step by step by looking at the output:

Normally I would say [Never parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), but with Hadoop, you don't have a choice here as there is no equivalent to `find`. (Since 2.7.0 there is a find, but it is very limited according to the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#find))

**Step 1:** recursive `ls`

```
$ hadoop fs -ls -R /path/to/folder/
```

**Step 2:** use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to pick files only and CSV files only
directories are recognized by their permissions that start with `d`, so we have to exclude those. And the CSV files are recognized by the last field ending with "csv":

```
$ hadoop fs -ls -R /path/to/folder/ | awk '!/^d/ && /\.csv$/'
```

make sure you do not end up with funny lines here which are empty or just the directory name ...

**Step 3:** continue using `awk` to process the time. I am assuming you have any standard awk, so I will not use GNU extensions. Hadoop will output the time format as `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`. This format can be sorted and is located in fields 6 and 7:

```
$ hadoop fs -ls -R /path/to/folder/  \
   | awk -v cutoff="$(date -d '-24 hours' '+%F %H:%M')" \
         '(!/^d/) && /\.csv$/ && (($6" "$7) > cutoff)'
```

**Step 4:** Copy files one by one:

First, check the command you are going to execute:

```
$ hadoop fs -ls -R /path/to/folder/  \
   | awk -v cutoff="$(date -d '-24 hours' '+%F %H:%M')" \
         '(!/^d/) && /\.csv$/ && (($6" "$7) > cutoff) {
            print "migrating", $NF
            cmd="hadoop fs -get "$NF" /path/to/local/"
            print cmd
            # system(cmd)
         }'
```

(remove `#` if you want to execute)

or

```
$ hadoop fs -ls -R /path/to/folder/  \
   | awk -v cutoff="$(date -d '-24 hours' '+%F %H:%M')" \
         '(!/^d/) && /\.csv$/ && (($6" "$7) > cutoff) {
            print $NF
         }' | xargs -I{} echo hadoop fs -get '{}' /path/to/local/
```

(remove `echo` if you want to execute)

Comment: Thanks! I will test this as soon as possible and let you know if it works. It looks promising. :) Thanks again.

Comment: I have not a chance to test this until today but I accept or bounty will expire. The problem is next: 
awk: cmd. line:1: 13:42 
awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ syntax error 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Step 4. Both examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer @kvantour. Do you suggest any link for someone that is now starts to learn ```awk```?

Comment: @NikSp Start with [awk one-liners explained](https://catonmat.net/awk-one-liners-explained-part-one) and then continue with reading the posix standard to understand its idea and then start looking things up in the gnu awk manual

Answer (score 1):

You can make it simpler by using "find" in combination with "cp", for example:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -type f -name "*.csv" | xargs cp -t /path/to/copy
```

If you want to clean your directory of files older than 24 hours, you can use:

```
find /path/to/files/ -type f -name "*.csv" -mtime +1 | xargs rm -f
```

Maybe you can implement them as script, then set it as a task on Cron.

Comment: hadoop fs -find was introduced in Apache Hadoop 2.7.0.

Comment: You can check the commands reference [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html)

Comment: That means you can adapt those simple commands to works with hadoop.

Comment: True, but `hadoop find` does not know `-mtime`