# Filtering Out Files in HDFS With Time Range

Tags: bash, hdfs

I have a list of files in HDFS which has to be filtered out for the latest n hr period through bash scripting

```
$ find . -name "*" -type f                  \
    -newermt "2019-09-22 23:59:59"          \
    ! -newermt "2019-09-23 23:59:59"        \
    -exec ls -lt --time-style=long-iso {} +
```

tried but still stuck with date level filteration cannot proceed futher

Expected is to filter out files in HDFS for any n hr period of the day

Comment: This answer might be helpful: [Copy files to local from multiple directories in HDFS for last 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55422684/8344060)

Answer (score 4):

This is an adaptation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364275/):

**note:** I was unable to test this, but you could test this step by step by looking at the output:

Normally I would say [Never parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), but with Hadoop, you don't have a choice here as there is no equivalent to `find`. (Since 2.7.0 there is a find, but it is very limited according to the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#find))

**Step 1:** recursive `ls`

```
$ hadoop fs -ls -R /path/to/folder/
```

**Step 2:** use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to pick files only. Directories are recognized by their permissions that start with `d`, so we have to exclude those.

```
$ hadoop fs -ls -R /path/to/folder/ | awk '!/^d/'
```

make sure you do not end up with funny lines here which are empty or just the directory name ...

**Step 3:** use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to process the time interval and select the directories out. I am assuming you have any standard awk, so I will not use GNU extensions. Hadoop will output the time format as `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`. This format can be sorted and is located in fields 6 and 7. The example below filters out all files that are between "2019-09-21 22:00" and "2019-09-21 23:00":

```
$ hadoop fs -ls -R /path/to/folder/  \
   | awk -v tStart="2019-09-21 22:00" -v tEnd="2019-09-21 23:00" \
         '(!/^d/) && (($6" "$7) >= tStart) && (($6" "$7") <= tEnd)'
```

Comment: last expression is missing some quotations: '(!/^d/) && (("$6" "$7") >= tStart) && (("$6" "$7") <= tEnd)'

Comment: @JuanZamora The expression you wrote in this comment, is incorrect. By quoting the awk-field-expressions, you actually don't substitute them by the field values.